# How to change an inputbox with a radio button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have this HTML code:

```
<div data-role="popup"  >
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="padding-top: 15px;width:24%">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true"> <a data-role="button" id="delivery-time-any" onclick="setTimeToAny(this);">Any</a>
 <a data-role="button" id="delivery-time-AM" onclick="setTimeToAM(this);">AM</a>
 <a data-role="button" id="delivery-time-PM" onclick="setTimeToPM(this);">PM</a>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="padding-right:5px;width:38%">
        <label for="wo-scheduled-time-window-after">Start Time:</label>
        <input type="text" name="scheduled_time_window_after" id="wo-scheduled-time-window-after" value="" data-mini="true" placeholder="--:--" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c" style="padding-left:5px;width:38%">
        <label for="wo-scheduled-time-window-before">End Time:</label>
        <input type="text" name="scheduled_time_window_before" id="wo-scheduled-time-window-before" value="" data-mini="true" placeholder="--:--" />
    </div>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <legend>Early Pick Up</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="early_pickup" id="wo-early-pick-up-yes" value="1" />
        <label for="wo-early-pick-up-yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="early_pickup" id="wo-early-pick-up-no" value="0" checked="checked" />
        <label for="wo-early-pick-up-no">No</label>
    </fieldset

>
</div>
```

What I want to do basically is to fill the input box called start time with 7:00 if I click on AM button. The problem is how can I make the radio button to set the input box to 05:00 if the Early Pick up is selected no matter what? By this I mean I can select the Early pick up and then click the AM button so I wouldn't want to have 7:00 back to the input box.

And this is my [jsfiddle URL](http://jsfiddle.net/1j7xter3/2/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your javascript

```
if(document.getElementById('wo-early-pick-up-yes').checked){
    strtTimeInpt.val('05:00:00');
    endTimeInpt.val('12:00:00');
}
else{
strtTimeInpt.val('07:00:00');
endTimeInpt.val('12:00:00');
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/1j7xter3/5/

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.

Comment: @SaulOrtega here is the fiddle for both buttons working http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/1j7xter3/7/

Answer (score 1):

I will show the logic for one of the ANY, AM, PM buttons and you can extrapolate to the other values.

```
// lets create a convience function to show is early
var isEarly = function () {
   console.log($("[name=early_pickup]:checked").val());
   return $("[name=early_pickup]:checked").val() == 1
}

var setTimeToAM = function (btn) {
    btn = $(btn);
    var popup = btn.closest('.block');
    var strtTimeInpt = popup.find('[name=scheduled_time_window_after]');
    var endTimeInpt = popup.find('[name=scheduled_time_window_before]');
    strtTimeInpt.val('07:00:00');
    // check if isEarly() so we can always set to 5:00
    if (isEarly()) {
        endTimeInpt.val('5:00:00');
    } else {
        endTimeInpt.val('12:00:00');
    }
};
// if the user ever clicks early pickup set it to 5, we could switch out the 5 on no
$("[name=early_pickup]").click(function (evt) {
    var endTimeInpt = $("#wo-scheduled-time-window-before");
    if(isEarly()) {
        endTimeInpt.val('5:00:00');
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1j7xter3/6/)

Comment: "extrapolate"... ?... You can tell by reading the question, the OP's first language is not English, why in the world would you put "extrapolate" in your answer lol...

Answer (score 1):

The crux of this looks to be grabbing what the radio buttons are toggled to and controlling the output in the set... functions

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1xkppde/1/)

For example in setTimeToAM:

```
if ($('#early-pickup :radio:checked').val() == 1) {
    strtTimeInpt.val('05:00:00');
    endTimeInpt.val('12:00:00');
} else {
    strtTimeInpt.val('07:00:00');
    endTimeInpt.val('12:00:00');
}
```

by getting the radio button values (and you can prefix like in the fiddle the fieldset with an id)

It's something you can repeat anywhere, knowing that if you have a radio button group, the actual value can be grabbed with `$('#fieldset :radio:checked').val()`